# Apply function to tree structure in racket

Tags: data-structures, struct, tree, scheme, racket

I'm trying to apply a function to a tree in the form of a Map but not sure how to exactly go about it. Here's my attempt..

```
    (define-struct node (value left middle right)#:transparent)

(struct emptyNode () #:transparent) ; leaf node

(define T (node 1 (node 2 (node 5 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) (emptyNode) (emptyNode))
                            (node 3 (emptyNode) (node 6 (emptyNode) (node 8 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)) (emptyNode)) (emptyNode))
                            (node 4 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (node 7 (emptyNode) (emptyNode) (emptyNode)))))

;                   1
;                 / |  \
;               2   3   4
;              /    |     \
;             5     6      7
;                   |
;                   8

;f
;   a function, f, used in MaptoTree
(define (f b)
  (* b 2))

;MaptoTree
;    takes a function, f, and a tree structure, tree, as parameters.
;    it should then produce a new tree structure where f has been applied to each value in the original tree
(define (MaptoTree f T)
  (if (pair? T)
      ((map (lambda (x) (MaptoTree f x)) (rest T)))
      (f T)))
```

edit: removed question about converting struct to list

Comment: Converting a tree to a list is a separate question, please make another post, together with the code you've written for it.

Comment: Oof. Ok will do! Thank you!

Comment: your last edit invalidated the answer. can't do that, according to SO rules. I restored the previous version. cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use the selectors for `node`, instead of `pair?`, `rest`, etc. We're using a `struct` to represent the tree, not a normal list.

After fixing that, we just have to traverse the tree applying the function on each value, building a new tree as we go - like this:

```
(define (MaptoTree f T)
  (if (emptyNode? T)
      (emptyNode)
      (node (f (node-value T))
            (MaptoTree f (node-left T))
            (MaptoTree f (node-middle T))
            (MaptoTree f (node-right T)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [data/lazytree](https://docs.racket-lang.org/lazytree/index.html) package (*disclosure: I'm the author*) to accomplish this, specifically the [tree-map](https://docs.racket-lang.org/lazytree/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._data%2Flazytree..rkt%29._tree-map%29%29) utility.

First, define a function to get the children of a node:

```
(define (node-children t)
  (list (node-left t)
        (node-middle t)
        (node-right t)))
```

Then, use it to create the tree representation:

```
(require data/lazytree)
(define t (make-tree node-children
                     T
                     #:with-data node-value
                     #:empty-pred emptyNode?))
```

You can now use tree-map to get the result:

```
(tree-map f t) ; => #<stream>
```

This returns a stream representing the resulting tree, which you could convert back to your original format if you need to:

```
(export-tree node
             (tree-map f t)
             #:empty-cons emptyNode)

=> (node 2
      (node 4
            (node 10
                  (emptyNode)
                  (emptyNode)
                  (emptyNode))
            (emptyNode)
            (emptyNode))
      (node 6
            (emptyNode)
            (node 12
                  (emptyNode)
                  (node 16
                        (emptyNode)
                        (emptyNode)
                        (emptyNode))
                  (emptyNode))
            (emptyNode))
      (node 8
            (emptyNode)
            (emptyNode)
            (node 14
                  (emptyNode)
                  (emptyNode)
                  (emptyNode))))
```